# three.js overdraw = true creates wireframe artifacts on transparent geometry

Tags: canvas, three.js, renderer

It seems that when overdraw is set to true, the canvas renderer actually expands the fill beyond the edges of the faces so they overlap a little.  This is fine normally, but when the material is transparent, these overlapped edges create an undesireable wireframe-type artifact.

see the pink arrows in the example: [Example](http://chrisweeks3d.com/webearth/WebEarthCanvas.html)

Is there a way to play with how much the fill is actually expanded?  I'm afraid the source code is simply over my head, but if someone could point out where that's handled (what line in the source), that would be much appreciated.  Failing that, hopefully someone knows another solution or workaround.

I realize the problem goes away when using the WebGL renderer, but I've been asked to make this work on Canvas if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. I'm afraid there is no solution for that using `CanvasRenderer`.

But if you want to try some values... this is the function that does that:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js#L1011-1025

You can try this...

```
idet = ( 1 / Math.sqrt( det ) ) * 0.5;
```

Then, with python installed in your system, go to /utils and run this to generate a new Three.js:

```
python build.py --common
```

And this for minifying it when you're done:

```
python build.py --common --minified
```

But I think you may get different results in different browsers.

Curious to know if you solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  This did work - sort of.  It seems the overlap get more severe as the geometry rotates away from the camera, so even though a value like .4 or .5 looks OK at first, it starts overlapping again as the animation progresses.  Obviously if the value goes too low, then the seams which the method is there to fix start showing up again.  The geometry is too complex to be sorted, so I've just left the value at .5 and decided to be satisfied that it mitigated the problem a little even if it's not fixed.  Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. the results did seem consistent across Chrome, Firefox, and Safari

Comment: Ah, interesting. Maybe I should put that in then.